# ReactJS: Image not rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render static images from images folder under src directory, however, it is not rendering, if i try to import any of the images directly and then pass in jsx like commented portion in `images` declaration it renders fine, also tried with `backgroundImage` property of css, it does not render anything.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Pizza from './components/pizza';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component {

  state = {
    open: false,
    active: null,
    categories: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      categories
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Pizza data={this.state}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const categories = [
  {"title":"Italian Pizza","link":"../images/italian-pizza.jpg",
   "id":"586537da62981d5fb8c21617", 
   "details": "aksnflafiafoasofhafhoahfohaofhoahfhashfohasfhofhahsofohahosf"}
];

export default App;
```

pizza.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import italian from '../images/italian-pizza.jpg'

const Pizza = ({data}) => {
  const images = data.categories.map((d,i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        {/* <img src={italian} /> */}
        <img src={`${d.link}`} />
      </div>
    )
  });


  return (
    <div className="pizza">
      <header className="header">Pizza</header>
      <div className="main">
        {data.categories.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <ul className="items">
                {images}
                {/* <li  style={{backgroundImage: `url(require(italian))`}} /> */}
              </ul>              
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
   )
}


Pizza.propTypes = {
  categories: PropTypes.array,
  open: PropTypes.bool,
  active: PropTypes.bool
}



export default Pizza;
```

Comment: Have you configured your webpack to use a loader for images file? The loader usually used is `file-loader` for this case.

Comment: What Jackyef said. If you are not too far into the project, maybe consider using create react app, so you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: maybe it is easier to put your images under public folder instead